# Перекрытие изображений Bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

Есть два [Bitmap'а](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) с произвольными изображениями на белом фоне. Нужно узнать, перекрываются ли эти изображения?

Вариант решения - сравнивать изображения по пикселям. Если пиксели с одинаковыми "координатами" заполнены на обоих рисунках, то изображения перекрываются.

```
    static bool IsBitmapsIntersect(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Math.Min(bitmap1.Width, bitmap2.Width); i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < Math.Min(bitmap1.Height, bitmap2.Height); j++)
            {
                if (bitmap1.GetPixel(i, j).ToArgb() != -1 && bitmap2.GetPixel(i, j).ToArgb() != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Есть ли какие-нибудь более быстрые/правильные решения этой задачи?

**UPD**

Воспользовался советом @Discord.
В итоге сделал обертку над Bitmap и GetPixel:

```
class BitmapInfo
{
    private readonly byte[] _argbBytes;

    private readonly int _pixelSize;

    private readonly int _stride;

    private readonly int _width;

    private readonly int _height;

    public BitmapInfo(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);

        _stride = Math.Abs(bitmapData.Stride);
        _argbBytes = new byte[_stride * bitmapData.Height];
        Marshal.Copy(bitmapData.Scan0, _argbBytes, 0, _argbBytes.Length);

        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        _width = bitmap.Width;
        _height = bitmap.Height;

        _pixelSize = Image.GetPixelFormatSize(bitmap.PixelFormat) / 8;
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get { return _width; }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get { return _height; }
    }

    public int GetPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        var startIndex = x * _stride + y * _pixelSize;
        int result = 0;

        for (var i = _pixelSize - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            result <<= 8;
            result |= _argbBytes[startIndex + i];
        }

        return result;
    }
}

    static bool IsBitmapsIntersect2(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2)
    {
        var bitmapInfo1 = new BitmapInfo(bitmap1);
        var bitmapInfo2 = new BitmapInfo(bitmap2);

        for (var i = 0; i < Math.Min(bitmapInfo1.Width, bitmapInfo2.Width); i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < Math.Min(bitmapInfo1.Height, bitmapInfo2.Height); j++)
            {
                if (bitmapInfo1.GetPixel(i, j) != -1 && bitmapInfo2.GetPixel(i, j) != -1)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Сравниваете сначала по крупной сетке если не перекрываются, то берете сетку мельче, если снова не перекрывается то тогда уж попиксельно сравниваете.

Comment: Какая разница? Это все равно перебор пикселей?

Comment: Сетка это намного меньше пикселей, а вероятность найти перекрытие быстрее больше.

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-net/thread954611.html

Comment: @cpp_user, не факт. При линейном чтении данные в кеш попадут, а при рандомном - нет. А вероятность встретить перекрытие в точке сетки сильно зависит от картинки.

Comment: вероятность != факт, ну и кэш тоже никто не обещает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetPixel` — это очень медленная функция. Всегда используйте [`LockBits`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) и вручную проходитесь по байтам, особенно если обрабатываете большие области.

В качестве альтернативы могу предложить сделать битмапы с бинарными масками ваших двух картинок. На третьем битмапе размером `min(b1.width, b2.width)` x `min(b1.height, b2.height)` совместить общую область картинок в режиме AND. Потом пройтись по данным с помощью `LockBits` и проверить, есть ли хоть какое-то пересечение.

Будет ли второй способ быстрее — не знаю, нужно мерять. Он может быть быстрее за счёт оптимизаций в железе/оси, потому что совмещение картинок может быть более быстрым.

Ещё один вариант — построить границы в виде многоугольников и искать пересечение, соответственно, многоугольников.

Comment: @Vlad: Только не забудьте про разницу между width * bpp и stride.

Answer (score 2):

Сравнение с -1 какое-то странное - не понял, чего ты хочешь этим добиться.

А по теме - использование GetPixel - это очень медленная операция. Надо делать LockBits, брать Scan0, превращать данные в массив и работать с этим массивом. Ну и не забыть UnlockBits :)

Comment: Я знаю, что картинки нарисованы на белом фоне. -1 - это он и есть.

Answer (score -3):

Вам нужен `RectangleF` и его метод `IntersectsWith`.

Comment: Он покажет пересечение прямоугольников. Чем оно поможет?

Comment: RectangleF rectf1 = bitmap1.getBounds(ref gu1);
RectangleF rectf2 = bitmap1.getBounds(ref gu2);
bool areTheyIntersects = rectf1.IntersectsWith(rectf2);

Comment: Они пересекаются, и я знаю об этом. Нужно узнать, пересекаются ли картинки внутри них.