# Максимально быстрое сравнение 2х скриншотов

Tags: c#, vb.net

Есть три скриншота. на них короткий текст с кодом типа X123XX123.

1. белый текст на темном фоне (без искажений)
2. красный текст на темном фоне (без искажений, текст совпадает с 1.)
3. белый текст на том же фоне что и всегда, но код другой. (без
   искажений)

Какой способ сравнения выбрать для быстрого сравнения вариантов 1-2 и 2-3?

- 1-2 Необходимо удостовериться что текст тот же но он стал красным.
- 2-3 Удостовериться что текст стал другим.

> Скриншоты размером около 150х80px.

Comment: Со 150*80 можно делать почти что угодно. В чём проблема с быстродействием?

Comment: Возможно проблем с быстродействием и нет,  это как дополнение к вопросу, в котором я как бы и незнал с чего начать.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, в [этом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433295/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-bitmap) вопросе я описывал класс-обертку над Bitmap. GetPixel у обертки работал быстрее, чем у Bitmap'а.

Comment: Можно предварительно сделать скриншоты черно-белыми, тогда при сравнении, если различий нет, то первый случай, иначе второй.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать так

```
   static bool Equality(Bitmap Bmp1, Bitmap Bmp2)  
    {
        var pixelTrue = 0.0;
        var pixelFalse = 0.0;
        if (Bmp1.Size == Bmp2.Size)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Bmp1.Width; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < Bmp1.Height; j++)
                {
                    var pixel1 = Bmp1.GetPixel(i, j);
                    var pixel2 = Bmp2.GetPixel(i, j);
                    if (pixel1 != pixel2) pixelFalse++;
                    else
                        pixelTrue++;
                }
        }
        else return false;
        var percentResult = (pixelTrue/(pixelTrue + pixelFalse))*100;
        return percentResult >= 97;
    }
```

Хотя шаг можно и увеличить!

Comment: `GetPixel` - это очень медленная операция. Гораздо лучше получать `Scan0` и сравнивать 2 массива. И идея с `PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed` что-то подозрительная.

Comment: @Qwertiy да Clone тут не нужен. Я даже не знал что так можно, если не трудно,  можешь дать пример как с помощью Scan0 определять цвет?

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/post5548691.html - как-то так (разверни там спойлер с кодом). И вот: http://www.cyberforum.ru/post5551672.html